# Can't show my NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I hope you guys can help me, normally I don't ask for help, but I just have this problem for a while.

I have this action which should create a new window from my XIB file

```
-(void)loginSuccess {
    NSLog(@"Login success delegate");

    Dashboard *dashboard = [[Dashboard alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Dashboard" owner:self];
    [dashboard showWindow:nil];
    [dashboard.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    BOOL loaded = [dashboard isWindowLoaded];

    NSLog(@"Dashboard window loaded: %i", loaded);  
    NSLog(@"Dashboard window visible: %i", [dashboard.window isVisible]);

}
```

And got this result

```
2011-11-15 10:32:23.525 DownloadApp[2676:707] Login success delegate
2011-11-15 10:32:23.533 DownloadApp[2676:707] Dashboard window loaded: 1
2011-11-15 10:32:23.533 DownloadApp[2676:707] Dashboard window visible: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a missing binding between the actual window object and the window property of the controller. Have you checked what happens if you check "Visible at launch" for the window?

Comment: By default is this checked, I have also checked the IBOutlet and this is connected as well.

Comment: My problem is that the Window is cloning right after it shows up.